# Выполнение задачи в фоне

Tags: android

Мне нужно выполнять определённую задачу в фоне, даже когда закрыто или свёрнуто приложение.

Использую Service, но просмотрев весь интернет понял, что Service постоянно работать не сможет, система рано или поздно его закроет.

Foreground Service мне не подходит, ибо будет постоянно видно уведомление в шторке.

Пробовал с AlarmManager, но то ли я с флагами напутал или что, но они так же работают периодически.

JobScheduler тоже не подходят, ибо минимальная версия их Api 21+.

Firebase Job Scheduler наверное работает только на минимальных Api(СКОРЕЕ ВСЕГО Я ОШИБАЮСЬ,Не проверял)

Evernote:Android-Job вообще не понимаю как пользоваться,чтобы задачи выполнялись в background.

Вот собственно мы и подошли к проблеме: Что же нужно использовать, чтобы можно было выполнять постоянно задачу в фоне, к примеру каждый час(обычная проверка какая-нибудь)?

В данный момент мой код выглядит вот так:

```
    public class MyTimerService extends Service implements Constants {
    NotificationManager nm;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    // run on another Thread to avoid crash
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    // timer handling
    private Timer mTimer = null;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        sp = getSharedPreferences(CHECK_SETTINGS,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // cancel if already existed
        if (mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
        } else {
            // recreate new
            mTimer = new Timer();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // schedule task
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, SERVIC_NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "AS onTaskRemoved called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent restartServiceTask = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),this.getClass());
        restartServiceTask.setPackage(getPackageName());
        PendingIntent restartPendingIntent =PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1,restartServiceTask, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager myAlarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        myAlarmService.set(
                AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
                restartPendingIntent);

//        int periodInMinutes = 1;
//        long periodInMiliseconds = periodInMinutes * 60 * 1000;
//        myAlarmService.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, periodInMiliseconds, periodInMiliseconds, restartPendingIntent);

        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Intent restartServiceTask = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),this.getClass());
        restartServiceTask.setPackage(getPackageName());
        PendingIntent restartPendingIntent =PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1,restartServiceTask, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager myAlarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        myAlarmService.set(
                AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
                restartPendingIntent);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "AS onDestroy called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }




    class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // run on another thread
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // display toast
                    push();
                }

            });
        }


    }
    public void push() {
        try {
            new MyTimerService.asynchronousGet().run();
            Log.i("Good","good");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Eror","errorororor");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void pushText(String str1,String str2){
        //String url="http://"+str2;

        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        Intent intent=new Intent(context,WebActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_INTENT,str2);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
// оставим только самое необходимое
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ico)
                .setContentTitle("Hodite")
                .setContentText(str1); // Текст уведомления

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND |
                Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        // ставим флаг, чтобы уведомление пропало после нажатия
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify((str1+str2).hashCode(),notification);
    }


    /*---------------------КЛАСС ДЛЯ СЧИТЫВАНИЕ ТЕКСТА ИЗ ФАЙЛА-----------*/
    public class asynchronousGet {
        private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        public void run() throws Exception {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(URL_TEXT_TXT)
                    .build();

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
                        if (!response.isSuccessful())
                            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                        Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                        for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                            System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                        }
                        // Log.i("Good",responseBody.string());
                        // System.out.print(responseBody.string().toString());//СЧИТАННЫЙ ТЕКСТ
                        String string=responseBody.string();
                        int count=0;
                        String[] strings=new String[2];
                        for (String str : string.split("\n")) {
                            Log.i("str",str);
                            strings[count]=str;
                            count++;
                        }
                        String s1;
                        String s2;
                        s1=sp.getString(notif_text, "notif_text");
                        Log.i("s1",s1);
                        s2=sp.getString(notif_url, "notif_url");
                        Log.i("s2",s2);
                        if(!(s1.trim().equals(strings[0].trim()) && s2.trim().equals(strings[1].trim()))){
                                /*Отправляем строки в уведомление*/
                            pushText(strings[0],strings[1]);

                                /*Сохранение переменных в SharedPreference*/
                            SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
                            e.putString(notif_text, strings[0]);
                            e.putString(notif_url, strings[1]);
                            e.commit(); // не забудьте подтвердить изменения
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```